# String helper method

Tags: java

I need a little help on how i could put in a helper method. This is the helper method I wrote.

```
public static String helper(String help) {
    help = help.toLowerCase();
    help = help.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
}
```

and this is how i used it in main method.

```
String help = RecursivePalindrome.helper(x);
```

If I keep it like this then on the helper method they ask me for a return value but if i put the `return help;` then the method doesn't execute correctly. If I change the helper method to void then i cant put String help on my main method.

This is what happens when i run the program:

```
Enter a word to test whether it is a palindrome or not(press quit to end.): RaceCar
'RaceCar' is not a palindrome.
```

See i put the helperclass to ignore the upper cases but it wont. RaceCar would be a palindrome but the uppercase makes the program say its not.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't execute correctly"? Returning `help` seems to be the right approach to me...

Comment: The helper method doesn't apply then. The helper is supposed to ignore case and ignore spaces and punctuation but it wont if I return help.

Comment: Remember that Strings are immutable in java. So your helper method really needs to return a String.

Comment: @user2059140: What do you mean by "ignore"? It's entirely unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes i know that but if I do that the program doesn't work correct so any suggestions on if I can change it from String to something else?

Comment: @JonSkeet like if i put RaCe it will ignore the capitals but that not the part I need help on.

Comment: What exactly do you want your `helper` to return?

Comment: @JonSkeet from what I can tell he appears to attempting to making something along the lines of java.util.Arrays.sort(Object[]). It is just meant to modify it, not necessarily return it.

Comment: I want it to ignore spaces,uppercase, and punctuations after the user inputs a word.

Comment: I did and it wont lower the cases or ignore anything returning same as user input

Comment: @user2059140 - sometimes, when you find it hard describing a problem with words, it helps to instead use code to illustrate your issue. This may be one of those times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
public static String helper(String help) {
    help = help.toLowerCase();
    help = help.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    help = help.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");
    return help;
}
```

Calling `helper` will return a `String` with all characters lowercased and every occurrence of whitespace or punctuation characters removed.

Example: `helper("Race Car#")` will return `"racecar"`

Answer (score 2):

Your method should return String. Also String in Java is immutable, any modification of string returns new string. Try this:

```
public static String helper(String help) {
    return help.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick palindrom calculator I created that works for RaceCar.....using ako's helper method.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args){
         System.out.println(palindrom(helper("RaceCar")));
    }

    public static String helper(String help){
         return help.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    }

    public static boolean palindrom(String pal)
    {
        int end = pal.length()-1;
        for(int i = 0; i<=pal.length()/2;i++)
        {
            if(pal.charAt(i)== pal.charAt(end-i));
            else 
            {
                return false;
            } 
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```